# Saving third-party images on third-party server

Tags: heroku, amazon-web-services

I am writing a service as part of which a user chooses an image from a url (not my domain) and later he and others can view that image.

I need to save this image to a third party server (S3).
After a lot of wasted time I found I can not do it from the client side due to security issues (I can't get the third party image data and send it from the client side without alerting the client, which is just bad)

I also do not want to do the uploading on my server because I run Rails on Heroku and the workers expansive.
So I though of two options:
use something like transloadit.com,
or write a service on EC2 that will run over my db, find where the rows where the images are not uploaded and upload them.
I decided to go for the EC2 and S3 because the solution i am writing is meant for enterprise and it seems that it will sound better as part of the architecture when presented to customers.

My question is: what is the setup i need so I can access the Heroku db from an external service?

Any better ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

So you want to effectively write a worker, but instead of doing it on Heroku you want to do it on EC2?   That feels like more work.

As for the database, did you see the [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#external-connections-ingress)? It shows how to get the URL.

PS.  Did you not find it in the docs?